# Electron as Superpartner of Higgs!

Tags: supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model, mssm

Can we identify Higgs as a superpartner of the electron in a massless case? We know, superpartners have the same mass so of course, we can't and one argument we can make there are two Higgs doublets in SUSY, so a single electron can't be mapped to two Higgs. Are there some other compelling arguments in opposition to this? If yes, then the resultant model would be more minimal. (A Higgs doublet and electron have the same standard model charges)

Comment: This is an excellent question. Apparently naïvely making the Higgs the superpartner of any neutrino or lepton leads to $L$-violation and large neutrino masses.

Comment: You may find https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4526 interesting